# Django pop up Form in forlopp

Tags: jquery, forms, django-templates

I need to display popupform when click. It displayed but when I want to close this form it take many time to close , i need to click X button many many times (i using Jquery) but If i give the pop up outside the forloop it becomes smooth. I don't know reason. Thank you about concerning my post
templates

```
{%for item in obj.data %}
            <article class="episode">
                <div class="episode__number">{{forloop.counter0}}</div>
                <div class="episode__content">
                    <div class="title"><p class="btnOpenForm">{{item.date}}</p></div>
                  <div class="story">
                    <p>Time: {{item.time}}</p>
                    <p>Adult: {{item.adult}}</p>
                    <p>Children: {{item.children}}</p>
                    <p>Combo: {{item.featuredCombo}}</p>
                    <p>Service: {{item.service}}</p>
                    <p>Add on: {{item.addOn}}</p>

                  </div>
                </div>

             </article>
            <div class="form-popup-bg">
                      <div class="form-container">
                        <button id="btnCloseForm" class="close-button">X</button>
                        <h1>Contact Us</h1>
                        <p>For more information. Please complete this form.</p>
                        <form action="">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Company Name</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">E-Mail Address</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="">Phone Number</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                          </div>
                          <button>Submit</button>
                        </form>
                      </div>
                </div>
                <script>
                  function closeForm() {
                  $('.form-popup-bg').removeClass('is-visible');
                }

                $(document).ready(function($) {

                  /* Contact Form Interactions */
                  $('.btnOpenForm').on('click', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    $('.form-popup-bg').addClass('is-visible');
                  });

                    //close popup when clicking x or off popup
                  $('.form-popup-bg').on('click', function(event) {
                    if ($(event.target).is('.form-popup-bg') || $(event.target).is('#btnCloseForm')) {
                      event.preventDefault();
                      $(this).removeClass('is-visible');
                    }
                  });


                  });
                </script>

        {%endfor%}
```

Comment: why do you need to put that popup inside forloop ?

Comment: I solved this.Thank you . I add every pop up index to unique